# Riemann zeta function inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I came across the following inequality while reading Patterson's book, "An Introduction to the theory of Riemann zeta function" on Page 107:

For $ |t^{2/3}|<X\leq|t|$ then

$$\left|\sum_{n\leq X}n^{-1/2-it}\right|\leq \sum_{j< \frac{\log X}{\log 2}}\left|\sum_{2^{-j-1}X<n<2^{-j}X}n^{-1/2-it}\right|$$

Why is the above inequality (especially the indices on right summation) true? So far I have come across the term "dyadic summation" but haven't been able to find a resource that outlines this technique. I appreciate any resources that prove the above inequality and also a reference for the dyadic summation technique

Comment: $\log X/\log2$, you mean just $\log_2X$?

Comment: @ThePirateBay: Yes! I included $logX/log2$ because the books originally writes it in that form

Comment: It is obvious $$\sum_{n \le x} a_n = \sum_{j \le \log_2(x)} \sum_{n \in [2^j,2^{j+1})} a_n + \sum_{n \in [2^{\lfloor \log_2(x) \rfloor},x]} a_n$$